# Get metcritic score from IMDbPY?

Tags: python, imdb, imdbpy

The imdbpy 5.0 changelog claims "support for obtaining metacritic score and URL":
http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/docs/Changelog.txt

I checked module documentations and source code and didn't really figure out how to get the metacritic score. Can somebody please push me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/alberanid/imdbpy/issues/new is the proper place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this commit: [Add support for obtaining metacritic score and URL](https://bitbucket.org/alberanid/imdbpy/commits/ca8ba3507d9c018007667c1c6226c1c38301d97c)

You will have to call `get_movie_critic_reviews` with a *movieID*. Have a look at the example files in the `bin/` directory.